# How to provide template for gridstack boxes jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I start to working with **gridstack.js** and i want to build layout dynamically from jquery.

But for this i want to provide some layout for boxes, like this:

[image]

So i do this, but problem is how i can build, this layout for boxes from script, because now i just add this to html.

```js
  var items = [
        { w: 3,content: 'my first widget' }, // will default to location (0,0) and 1x1
        { w: 3, content: 'another longer widget!' } // will be placed next at (1,0) and 2x1
    ];
    var grid = GridStack.init();
    grid.load(items);
```

```css
    .stantion-box {
        display: flex;
    }

    .stantion-text {
        justify-content: right;
    }

    .image-box {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .grid-stack {
        background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    }

    .grid-stack-item-content {
        color: #2c3e50;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #18bc9c;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gridstack@4.3.1/dist/gridstack.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gridstack@4.3.1/dist/gridstack-h5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a class="btn btn-default" onClick="addNewWidget()" href="#">Add Widget</a></div>
    <br />
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="grid-stack">
        <div class="text-center card text-white grid-stack-item newWidget ui-draggable" gs-x="0" gs-y="2" gs-w="3" gs-h="1">
    <div class="card-body grid-stack-item-content ui-draggable-handle stantion-box">
        <div class="stantion-icon">
            <img src="https://www.ccifr.ru/wp-content/themes/ccifr/img/no-image.png" class="image-box"/>
        </div>
        <div class="stantion-text">
            <div class="stantion-title">
                <span>Drag me into the dashboard!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="stantion-descr">
                <span>some descr</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>


    </div>
```

So i want to build first box on the layout use js, to dynamically boxes build from here

```
var items = [
    { w: 3,content: 'my first widget' }, // will default to location (0,0) and 1x1
    { w: 3, content: 'another longer widget!' } // will be placed next at (1,0) and 2x1
];
```

How i can defind standart layout for boxes?

Comment: just add your html text in your script and use `$('.container').html('<!--your html code here-->');`

Comment: @groovy_guy not best solution